# Old values coming in POST from Jquery Modal Box

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, modal-dialog

So I am messing with very stupid issue,There is normal HTML form which I am opening in Modal Box for updating the values.When I change the values of any Text Box and click on button for Ajax Call, **there is Old values coming in POST instead of changed value**.

For example if there is Value `5` and i changed it to `10` and fire Ajax but in POST data there is still `5`.I am using `on` for getting current values.

Here is part of my HTML code :

```
<form action="" id="UpdateBind_data">
   <input type="text" id="weightage" name="weightage" value="<?php echo $mapping_data->weightage; ?>">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary UpdateBind">Update</button>
</form>
```

Jquery :

```
 $("body").on("click", ".UpdateBind", function() {
        var Datastring = $("#UpdateBind_data").serialize();// Retrive the old values not the changed ones.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: updatedbindlink,
            data: Datastring,
            datatype: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.res)
                {
                    alert("Mapping data successfully Inserted");
                }
                else
                {
                    //error
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it because your forms submits before executing the JQuery bind? Try this:

```
 $("body").on("click", ".UpdateBind", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var Datastring = $("#UpdateBind_data").serialize();// Retrive the old values not the changed ones.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: updatedbindlink,
            data: Datastring,
            datatype: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.res)
                {
                    alert("Mapping data successfully Inserted");
                }
                else
                {
                    //error
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you paste your hole javascript and form code please?